# How to get all models of a class in all apps of a Django project

Tags: python, django

I have a model class `AppModelActions` that inherits from `CustomModel` that inherits from `django.db.models`, and I use it in all apps of the project.

I want to get all instances of `AppModelActions` in all apps, from a command file in one of the apps. I can't import each one explicitly because I want this command to work dynamically. I tried to import the instances programmatically, but it didn't work (I get this error: `KeyError: 'AppModelActions').

This is my code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf import settings
from GeneralApp import models

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = _("""Run this commando to populate an empty database with initial data required for Attractora to work.
                For the momment, this models are considered on 'populate_db' command:
                    - InventoriManagerApp.InventoryManagerAppActions """)

    def populate_db(self):
        applications = settings.INSTALLED_APPS

        for application in applications:
            try:
                import applications.models
            except:
                pass

        #from InventoryManagerApp.models import InventoryManagerAppActions

        models_to_populate = (vars()['AppModelActions'])
        #models_to_populate = (InventoryManagerAppActions,)

        for model_to_populate in models_to_populate:
            self.populate_model('InventoryManagerApp', model_to_populate)

    def populate_model(self, app_label, model_to_populate):
        model_to_populate_instance = model_to_populate()
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model=model_to_populate_instance.name)

        if hasattr(model_to_populate_instance, 'populate_data'):
            populate_data = model_to_populate.populate_data
            for record in populate_data:
                for key, value in record.items():
                    setattr(model_to_populate_instance, key, value)
                try:
                    model_to_populate_instance.save()
                except IntegrityError:
                    print("{} already exists.".format(model_to_populate_instance))
                # else:
                #     new_permission = Permission.objects.create(code_name=)

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.populate_db()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain all subclasses by iteratively updating a set of children:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    # ...

    def populate_db(self):
        from some_app.models import AppModelActions

        children = set()
        gen = [AppModelActions]
        while gen:
            children.update(gen)
            gen = [sc for c in gen for sc in c.__subclasses__()]

        # do something with children
        # ...
```

After this, the `children` is a set containing *all* models that are subclasses of `AppModelActions` (including this model). In case you do not want to include `AppModelActions`, swap the two lines in the `while` loop.

Since you use a command, Django will first load all the `models.py` files from the installed apps, and so the subclasses are registered before the `handle(..)` function is executed, so the `children` set will contain all child models that are in *installed* apps.

Note that child-models can be *abstract*, so you might want to perform an extra filtering, such that only *non*-abstract models are used. For example post-process it with:

```
non_abstract_children = [c for c in children if not c._meta.abstract]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Willem Van Onsem, you give me a very complete guidance in the topic. My command now works perfectly